# Microsoft Web Expression 3.0 syntax coloring

Tags: microsoft-expression-web

Is there any way to import Visual Studio 2008 color schemes into Expression Web 3.0?
I can change the font and the size of the font, I can also change pretty much every aspect
of the coloring from the menu Tools->Page Editor Options... but is there a way to IMPORT settings from VS 2008, I don't want to set everything manually.